# Connection reset by 140.82.121.4 port 22. How can I fix this error in Git

Tags: github

Connection reset by 140.82.121.4 port 22. I connected with SHH terminal. Basically everything is working. But when I do (PUSH) all the connection is broken and again this error is coming. (Connection reset by 140.82.121.4 port 22.)

I couldn't find the answer to this anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are connected through SSH to the machine where you then want execute git commands.

And since 140.82.121.4 references GitHub, you might be trying to push to GitHub using a Git remote repository SSH URL like `git@github.com:aUser/aProject`.

Depending of your environment, egress SSH request might be blocked (I known I cannot use SSH URLs at work for instance)

Try instead an HTTPS URL:

```bash
cd /path/to/repository
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/aUser/aProject
git push
```

Comment: Hello. I checked with https and got these errors.   Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
rejeLogon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/rejep-rejepow/rejep-rejepow.git/'

Comment: First, make sure ti use a PAT as password: [a classic one, with scope repo](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token#creating-a-personal-access-token-classic). Second, you might want to install a Git credential helper to cache those credentials and not have to enter every time.  Like [GCM](https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/blob/release/docs/install.md#linux).